# Display to Smart TV via HDMI without going into recovery mode

Tags: lubuntu, hdmi

I have an old desktop, with a AMD Athlon(tm) 64 X2 Dual Core Processor 5600+, and a RV770 [Radeon HD 4850] VGA compatible controller, running Lubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. The computer has  a DVI-I port, with a cable converting it to HDMI. Using this cable, I have connected the computer to a new LG 43NANO TV, which has several HDMI in ports.

When I boot Lubuntu via recovery mode, I am able to get to the login screen, and log in to the desktop. I have made an autostart file with the following content, which seems to allow for a suitable display.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=LXRandR autostart
Comment=Start xrandr with settings done in  LXRandR
Exec=sh -c 'xrandr --output DVI-I-2 --mode=3840x2160 --output DVI-I-1 --off'
```

But if I boot normally, after the GRUB menu, the TV complains that there is no input, and I never see the login screen on the TV.

I wonder why going in through recovery mode makes the TV more amenable to displaying an image, and what I can do to be able to be able to use Lubuntu on this TV without this workaround.

Comment: by going through 'recovery' mode you're using a *fallback* video display '*driver*', rather than the radeon which would be used normally..

Comment: I see, so how can I set that as the default? The whole desktop is working fine with my workaround.